# MYSQL: getting items not belonging to a category

Tags: mysql

I have two tables representing posts and its categories.
Here is a simplified table schemas:

```
posts                post_categories
-----               ----------------
-id                 -post_id
-title              -cat_id
-text
```

I'm need to get all posts that **does not belongs to category "5"** with this:

```
SELECT * FROM `posts` WHERE id NOT IN( SELECT id FROM `posts`, 
`post_categories` AS cat WHERE cat.cat_id=5 AND posts.id=cat.post_id )
```

I'm using a subquery because a post can belong to no category, so If I do a simple:

```
cat_id!=5 AND posts.id=post_id
```

I would not get those posts with no categories.

Is there a better approach than doing a subquery?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Doing a left-join is usually "better" in terms of performance. Do it like this:

```
SELECT * FROM `posts` 
    LEFT JOIN `post_categories` AS cat ON posts.id=cat.post_id AND cat.cat_id=5
WHERE  cat.cat_id IS NULL
```

Comment: Thank you, fine that I could help

Answer (score 2):

You do a LEFT JOIN:

```
SELECT DISTINCT `field1`,`field2`...etc FROM `posts` a LEFT JOIN `post_categories` b ON a.id=b.post_id  WHERE b.cat_id <> 5
```

Should work!

Comment: That simply finds all posts

Comment: Not absolutely, but i'm sure that it will give you all posts with _any_ category other than 5. That is not what was asked.

Comment: That's exactly what they wanted from what I could tell... I may be wrong.

Comment: I tested this and it worked although it gave me duplicated records. But maybe because I have other conditions (date ranges mainly) I omitted from my question just for convenience.

Comment: what do you mean by duplicated records? if you replace the * with the fields you want with 'distinct' key word... then you should be fine see my EDIT

Comment: This would eliminate the need for a subquery... and would be more efficient

Comment: As I said I have other conditions in my query and some post-processing so maybe duplication is caused by external factors. Just saying that as a drop-in replacement didn't fully work in my environment.

Answer (score 1):

What about:

```
SELECT * FROM `posts` WHERE id NOT IN( SELECT id FROM
`post_categories` WHERE cat_id!=5)
```

I'm not sure why you need 'posts' in your sub query. All you want is to get from 'post_categories' the posts with category != 5, then get their info from 'posts'.

Comment: ok... yeah obviously I did an unnecessary relation in that subquery, I  didn't see that. But what I mean with my question is if I can do it with another approach rather than with a subquery.